# Create users for a WPF application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I'm creating an application on which I want different users to use it. I want to insert a variable, only modifiable at development mode. I think maybe there should be a way of using the `App.Settings` of the WPF Application, but, after one hour googling, I don't have a clear idea yet.

So, I need:

- A variable that makes the WPF Application run at administration or client scope
- If I have that variable in a specific role, I want to disable some controls

Any idea on where to look for a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could add to the base class of your `ViewModels` a property which contains the value reflecting the mode. As next step you could bind the `IsEnabled` property of the controls, which shall have this behavior, on this property of their related `ViewModel`.

Since you don't want to provide different modes with different states a.s.o., this seems to be the best approach.